# ReflectedWorkItemIDField Name for basic and scrum processes

Tags: azure-devops-migration-tools

Azure-devops-migrations-tools only works with custom processes , If we need to use the tool for existing (Basic, Scrum ,CMMI )  , What will be the Reflectedworkitemid Field name for the existing predefined processes in Azure devOps Services .

My requirement is to move work items from one project in one organization to another project different organization in Azure Devops Services.

I am stuck at the reflected workitemID ?

Attaching Logs

```
[10:47:34 ERR]  Error running query
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.ValidationException: TF51005: The query references a field that does not exist. The error is caused by «[Scrum.ReflectedWorkItemId]».
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.Query.Initialize(WorkItemStore store, String wiql, IDictionary context, Int32[] ids, Int32[] revs, Boolean dayPrecision)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.WorkItemStore.Query(String wiql, IDictionary context)
   at MigrationTools._EngineV1.Clients.TfsWorkItemQuery.GetWorkItemsFromQuery(TfsWorkItemMigrationClient wiClient) in D:\a\1\s\src\MigrationTools.Clients.AzureDevops.ObjectModel\_EngineV1\Clients\TfsWorkItemQuery.cs:line 40
[10:47:34 FTL] Error while running WorkItemMigration
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.ValidationException: TF51005: The query references a field that does not exist. The error is caused by «[Scrum.ReflectedWorkItemId]».
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.Query.Initialize(WorkItemStore store, String wiql, IDictionary context, Int32[] ids, Int32[] revs, Boolean dayPrecision)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.WorkItemStore.Query(String wiql, IDictionary context)
   at MigrationTools._EngineV1.Clients.TfsWorkItemQuery.GetWorkItemsFromQuery(TfsWorkItemMigrationClient wiClient) in D:\a\1\s\src\MigrationTools.Clients.AzureDevops.ObjectModel\_EngineV1\Clients\TfsWorkItemQuery.cs:line 70
   at MigrationTools._EngineV1.Clients.TfsWorkItemQuery.GetWorkItems() in D:\a\1\s\src\MigrationTools.Clients.AzureDevops.ObjectModel\_EngineV1\Clients\TfsWorkItemQuery.cs:line 30
   at MigrationTools._EngineV1.Clients.TfsWorkItemMigrationClient.FilterExistingWorkItems(List`1 sourceWorkItems, TfsWiqlDefinition wiqlDefinition, TfsWorkItemMigrationClient sourceWorkItemMigrationClient) in D:\a\1\s\src\MigrationTools.Clients.AzureDevops.ObjectModel\_EngineV1\Clients\TfsWorkItemMigrationClient.cs:line 54
   at VstsSyncMigrator.Engine.WorkItemMigrationContext.InternalExecute() in D:\a\1\s\src\VstsSyncMigrator.Core\Execution\MigrationContext\WorkItemMigrationContext.cs:line 120
   at MigrationTools._EngineV1.Processors.MigrationProcessorBase.Execute() in D:\a\1\s\src\MigrationTools\_EngineV1\Processors\MigrationProcessorBase.cs:line 47
```

Answer (score 0):

Technically, you could of course use an unused field from the original process templates (Scrum, ...) and then change the value accordingly in the configuration (e.g. integrated in build).

Why not just derive the process and add the field as described in the [documentation](https://nkdagility.github.io/azure-devops-migration-tools/server-configuration.html#:%7E:text=Inherited%20Templates%20%2D%20the%20future)? The inheritance process model actually makes this approach super easy. After migration, you can then simply switch your team project back to the model without the migration field.